# Rails voting system - See live results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, live-streaming

I'm looking to create a Rails app where users can, for example, vote on a topic, and their choice would be saved to the database. Following this, a results page would be displayed with **live** results. This means that as other people vote, the graph or simple text data would  update with new votes or on a timer.

I'm sure this is possible, but I'm not sure how to begin implementing this. Are there any gems that I can easily drop in, or do I have to construct something using live streaming, or something else of the sort?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution will be to implement an action that will return your current data in json, and then poll it from javascript with time intervals.

```
(function poll(){
   setTimeout(function(){
      $.ajax({ url: "your action url", success: function(data){
        // update data here
      }, dataType: "json"});
  }, 30000);
})();
```

Complex, but more efficient solution will be to use `WebSockets` to have a live connection and data coming through it.

To implement it with `WebSockets` you can use something simple, like 
https://github.com/igrigorik/em-websocket

See examples on project's github page. All you'll need to do is send messages to all connected sessions every time there is a new vote. Or throttle that process in case you have to much votes per second.

Comment: Downvoter care to explain?

Comment: Not sure why downvoted - but thanks for the suggestion! Any suggestions on how to implement WebSockets for a live connection to deliver database voting data? Thanks!

Comment: @dwmcc if you don't have hundreds of users online, i would really recommend to go with polling, much easier to start. Wait a bit, i'll add more info on websockets

Comment: hopefully the app will have up to a few hundred concurrent users which may slow down the polling - but I will try it out. I look forward to your info on WebSockets! Thanks so much!